# How to create a shopping cart using Webmethod and Ajax in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I want to create a shopping cart in that the products would be fetched from database. I would create a web method but need to call this webmethod using ajax.

How to refresh the cart on the same page whenever new item is added using ajax ?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialise your shopping cart at load time

```
let shoppingCart = []; // array of objects
```

First define what information you want to store in it that will be the attributes of your cart item object
for instance : id, quantity, lable, price, sum
start from that and give us feed back

then we'll help you further